# Stack Exchange App For iPhone X And Above

Tags: discussion, status-declined

Although I am new to the forum, I have also been reading articles without an account for months.

Today, I signed up for an account. I have downloaded the stack exchange app and have noticed that it hasn’t been updated for the new screen style of the iPhone X and above. As an iPhone 11 Pro user, this is very frustrating. So, is there an update in the works for a better experience. In my option, not having updated the app in 3 years is unacceptable for a forum app.

Does anyone else think that this is completely ridiculous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The app hasn’t been updated for the new screen style of the iPhone X

> not having updated the app in 3 years is unacceptable for a forum app.

This is officially [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

Source [Q&A blank in Stack Exchange Android app v1.0.95 - S10e/Android 10 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/267099), answer by [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis) (a Stack Exchange developer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That’s a shame. Anyway, all the best in future

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote this in support of your opinion, or downvote in protest at the official stance.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not my opinion. I've clearly quoted the developers response.

Comment: and frankly, there's a few things in my workflow, like notifications that don't work without the app, so \o/, maybe they'll change their mind in 6-8....

Comment: @DavidPostill - I meant the 'unacceptable'… that's the bit I do agree with :P I've known for a long time that they've effectively killed the app. "View it in your mobile browser". Nope, not gonna be doing that, tyvm. When the app eventually becomes completely unusable, I will simply stop accessing SE from my mobile. Simple as that.